# Setting up HTTP Request Sampler for POST Method in JMeter Test Plan

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, cas

I have a web application where all the pages/services are secured using Central Authentication Service (CAS) based security. I need to perform a load testing on a page using HTTP POST request but have no idea how to configure HTTP Request Sampler for this POST method having access through security of CAS.
I can get the Ticket to get access to the page manually from the browser which is as follows:

```
https://<server>:<portX>/testweb-cas/oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize?ticket=ST-17-J5jknSbPrU1pQ5vFK0bL-testweb.au
```

Now I want to set up HTTP POST Request Sampler for :

`http://<server>:<portY>/Xyz/pages/details.xhtml` using `authorization` from above link.

I haven't used HTTP Request POST sampler before in JMeter, and not really getting the desired output using the available solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easiest way:**

Use HTTP Test Script recorder, which records the traffic from the browser and build JMeter Test Plan using `HTTP Sampler`.

**Another way** is, to manually add `HTTP Samplers` to the `Thread Group`. Select `Post` from `Method` drop down. Mention the body of the request `Body data` section. Add `HTTP Header Manager` if you want to add Headers to the request, like `Authorization` header.

**Note:** Don't take `Authorization` value manually by visiting the browser. Record the navigation, so HTTP Sampler will be added for that request. Add `Regular Expression Extractor` to retrieve Authorization value from the response and store it in a variable, so that you can use it in the POST request.

**Note:** Add `HTTP Cookie Manager` (if not already added during recording) so that JMeter automatically takes care of Cookie based authentication.

References:

1. [HTTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
2. [Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
3. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)