# jmeter how to sample POST request data from a set of images

Tags: apache, http, post, jmeter

The JMeter [Test Plan generator](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-started-jmeter-basic-tutorial) for HTTP POST [appears to require a fixed set of request data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818798/setting-up-http-request-sampler-for-post-method-in-jmeter-test-plan) configured for the POST request.

In my use case, I want to sample different POST requests to replay against a sever, where each request will vary by having a different image sent in the POST data, from a set of image files already collected from logs of requests against the server.

Is this possible in JMeter? If so, how do I configure so that when the log replay begins, it chooses image files from a local set of images to randomly include as part of the POST data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create several `HTTP requests` within `Random Controller`, which itself should be inside `Loop Controller`.

[image: jmeter]

Loop controller settings allow you to set the number of repetitions. Each HTTP request shall have different images.

[image: HTTP request settigns]

**UPDATE**

Should you have a desire to have many of thousands different files, you can turn to user variables, and then use it in file name to a picture `img-${b}.png`

[image]

[image]

---

Comment: If I understand right, you are saying to manually add the base64 image encoded string as a fixed value in a POST request. Do this for several images, then use a loop controller to switch between those pre-defined requests? What to do if there are hundreds or thousands of test images? I wouldn't want to manually create thousands of requests inside the JMeter menus.

Comment: Do you really want hundred of thousands different requests?

Comment: Yes, very much. That's a basic part of how we use blazemeter for testing many services. Often it is log replays of thousands of queries. In this case it's an image processing service and we have a suite of acceptance testing data, we'd like to know performance in aggregate across the whole set of images.

Comment: The update makes it seem like the parameter would take on a single value, e.g. such as `host` in a companion yaml configuration file for the .jmx file. The use case is to draw the file name randomly from a folder full of images (or iterate and draw them all once, etc.). Similar to supplying a log file with a different GET request on each line, I want to supply a directory path with different images to convert to base64 and add into the POST request.

Comment: This is exactly what it does. Images in this example have to be named as `img-<NUMBER>.png`. Variable `b` is randomly selected for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: So does it mean that the value entered in for 'File Path' must include the specific folder path? It must be a path relative to the directory where the .jmx file resides? How could that whole path be overridden in the yaml configuration? Something like `${images}/${name-pattern}.jpg`?

Comment: I reckon it could be an absolute path, if you like. Not sure about yaml configuration, though.